# Having Trouble With a Javascript Scroller without a Button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some issues with a personal website that I'm designing. I would like the list items to be able to scroll to a desired position once pressed. I had previously been using  to do this, but I was unsure if it was better to use JS for this or an anchor. I am ridiculously unskilled in JavaScript, but I couldn't figure out how to get the anchors to call the JS scroller method. This is what I have so far:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Jackson Singleton</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/stylesheet.css">

    <div id="heading">
      <h1><a href="index.html">jackson<span id ="lastName">singleton</span></a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="navBar">
      <ul id="navList">
        <li id="home">home</li>
        <li id="port"><a href>portfolio</a></li>
        <li id="inqr"><a href>inquiries</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </head>
  <br  />
  <body>
    <script src="JavaScript/script.js"></script>
    <div class="bodyPanel" id="portBody">
      <h1 id="portHeading">portfolio</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="bodyPanel" id="inqrBody">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the JS:

```
var portLink = document.getElementById('port');
portLink.onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById('portHeading').scrollIntoView();
}
```

Please help!

Comment: If you want this to be a smooth scrolling animation, look up the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function for jQuery. Otherwise, you don't need JavaScript, just set the href attribute for the link equal to the id of the element you want to jump to, like `<a href="#my-element">Scroll to My Element</a>`. There is a way to animate the smooth scroll with pure JavaScript, but seeing as how you are "ridiculously unskilled", I think going with the jQuery solution would be the easiest.

Comment: This link is all that is need, Jquery is your best choice and you also need to give those anchor tags values for the href attribute. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to link an anchor tag to some section of the page you need to give an id to an element in that section, e.g. `id="part1"` and then in the `href` of your anchor tag you would say `href="#part1"`. This would perform an instant scroll to wherever that element with id part1 is on the page.

For smooth scrolling, jQuery is your best option. 
Read the content of this page on how to make a smooth scroll instead on an instant scroll, they have a demo and source code on how to do this.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and the speedy response!